# How to present a ViewController with a Navigationbar programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When presenting my viewcontroller this way I don't get a navigationbar, even though the viewcontroller is embedded in a navigation controller in the interface builder.

```
        if let stockVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Stock") as? StockTableViewController {
        stockVC.stockToDisplay = commonData.stock.filter { $0.productID.contains(product) }
        // No NavigationBar with this one
        navigationController?.present(stockVC, animated: true)
        // No NavigationBar with this one
        self.present(stockVC, animated: true)
    }
```

I know the navigationBar works, because if I set the ViewController as initial in the storyboard, it shows.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you present a view controller, it is not part of the current navigation stack. You need to create a new navigation controller with your stockVC contained in it, and present the new navigation controller:

```
if let stockVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Stock") as? StockTableViewController {
    stockVC.stockToDisplay = commonData.stock.filter { $0.productID.contains(product) }
    let stockNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: stockVC)
    self.present(stockNavigationController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: #  
Thanks! That makes sense, and it surely worked. But now my navigation controller in IB has no use right, because we do it all in code? If I change the code to instantiate the navigation controller in the IB instead, it works, but the data I pass in (stockToDisplay) are not used. 

(if let navVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: “StockNav”) {
   self.present(navVC, animated: true)
  }

Is there any right/best way to do this? Make it all in code, or another way in IB?